# I am trying to build a java sorter, but I keep getting an error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```java
public class Sorter{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {9, 3, 5, 6, 2, 2, 53, 5, 75, 78, 68, 6, 5, 44, 5, 63356, 242, 25};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      int minIndex = i;

      for (int j = i + 1; i < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
          minIndex = j;
        }
      }

      int temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
      arr[minIndex] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

It is supposed to sort the array, but I get this error. I am really confused what to do. I am trying to use the selection sort algorithm.:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
   at Sorter.main(Sorter.java:8)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: In the second `for` you probably meant `j<arr.length` with your current code the condition with `i` will always be true (well until j will reach array length and you get the exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line

```
for (int j = i + 1; i < arr.length; j++)
```

you should change the condition to `j < arr.length` (replace `i` with `j`). and your sort code has another problem too.
the line you wrote an if-statement for check `j` index of `arr` are smaller or not. you should change the condition to `arr[j] < arr[minIndex]` (replace `i` with `minIndex`).

The code after this edits should be this.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {9, 3, 5, 6, 2, 2, 53, 5, 75, 78, 68, 6, 5, 44, 5, 63356, 242, 25};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int minIndex = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }

        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
        arr[minIndex] = temp;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9, 25, 44, 53, 68, 75, 78, 242, 63356]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the variable `i`.  It goes from `0` to the `length` of the array.  Your array has `18` elements numbered `0` to `17`.  The variable `j` is set to the value of `i+1`.  When `i` is `17` in the outer loop, `j` will be set to `18`.  Index `18` (`arr[18]`) is beyond the end of the array.